# Renaming the value of a proportional symbols layer in Table of Contents in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, classification, table-of-contents

In the case of a - for example - graduated colors or graduated symbols layer, it is easy to rename the value in the Table of Contents. I always click the value name and press F2.

However, pressing F2 on the value name of a proportional symbols layer in ArcMap doesn't give you the opportunity to rename the value. Is there any other way to do so?

So, I'm trying to change the name of the 'PURBAN'-value in the second layer.
[image: So I'm trying to change 'PURBAN']

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you are viewing and trying to change?

Comment: Yes, of course, just did so!

Comment: Try the "Label" in the Symbology tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach to renaming is the correct as you mentioned and discussed [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/renaming-a-layer.htm)

> Click the layer name or the feature description in the table of contents to change its name. A box will appear around the name, and the cursor will blink inside.
>
> You can also select an item in the table of contents and press the F2 key to rename it.
>
> Type in the new name.

However, with proportional symbols, when you select the field in the value drop down box like here:

[image]

that is what will show up in the TOC

[image]

I'm not exactly sure why the renaming isn't enabled in the TOC, when working with proportional symbol content however I do agree that the field name doesn't allow for renaming in the TOC.

To do so, you can go the properties menu for that shapefile you set the proportional symbols, then to the field's tab. You could read more [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/setting-symbol-legend-properties.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_EF141EE61CF84D929F38AD686AF978BF)

[image]